# Using typescript in state slices of Reduxjs/toolkit

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-typescript

I'm new to the react world, i'm trying to write an app using NextJs + reduxjs/toolkit and MUI and TypeScript.
I'm having trouble with the TypeScript part of the reduxjs/toolkit.
This is my **store/user-preferences-silce.ts **

```
import { ThemeOptions } from "@mui/material";
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { defaultThemeOption } from "../styles/theme/themeOptions";

export type UserPreferencesSliceState = {
  theme: ThemeOptions;
};

const initialState: UserPreferencesSliceState = {
  theme: defaultThemeOption,
};

const userPreferencesSlice = createSlice({
  name: "userPreferences",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    toggleThemeMode(state) {
      state.theme!.palette!.mode =
        state.theme!.palette!.mode === "light" ? "dark" : "light";
    },
  },
});

export const userPreferencesActions = userPreferencesSlice.actions;
export default userPreferencesSlice.reducer;
```

Then my **store/index.ts**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userPreferencesReducer from "./user-preferences-slice";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    userPreferences: userPreferencesReducer,
  },
});

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export default store;
```

But when i'm using the state like in my **Layout.tsx**

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from "../../store";
import { ThemeOptions } from "@mui/material";
import { useMemo } from "react";

const Layout: React.FC = (props) => {
  const themeOptions: ThemeOptions = useSelector<RootState>(
    (state) => state.userPreferences.theme
  );
  const theme = useMemo(() => {
    return createTheme(themeOptions);
  }, [themeOptions]);

  return <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{props.children}</ThemeProvider>;
};

export default Layout;
```

I got this warning

> Type 'unknown' not assignable to type 'ThemeOptions'

referred to this part

```
 const themeOptions: ThemeOptions = useSelector<RootState>(
    (state) => state.userPreferences.theme
  );
```

Can someone help my understand how to handle the type of the redux slices? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [in the `useSelector` type definition](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/43d1cc61c0ed257fb8d6ddcb6691020b64f0210b/src/hooks/useSelector.ts#L24), the hook accepts two generic types: The first one, `TState`, is the store state type, and the second one `Selected` is the selectors return type. By default, both generics are optional and the return type is `unknown`, that's why TypeScript complains.

There are two possible solutions to this:

1. you can either explicitly state the expected return type for your selector by passing `ThemeOptions` as the second generic type:

   ```
   const themeOptions: ThemeOptions = useSelector<RootState, ThemeOptions>(/* ... */)
   ```
2. or you leave the work to TypeScript by using [type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html):

   ```
   const themeOptions = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.userPreferences.theme)
   ```

   Take note on how I removed the generic `<RootState>` declaration and added its declaration to the selector parameter instead. This way, it will infer the `TState` from the method signature and `Selected` from its return type. Additionally, I removed the `: ThemeOptions` type declaration on the const to further infer the type, which is optional.